# Can I use `when` with `whereHas` in a Laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a `whereHas` to a Laravel query but only if a variable is true. I'm trying the below which doesn't error but doesn't return anything when it should.

```
$assets = Asset::with('media')
            ->when($category, function ($q) use ($category) {
                return $q->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($category) {
                    $query->whereId($category);
                });
            })->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
```

If `$category` is true nothing is returned. If `$category` is false all is returned. It works without the `when` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code, it is working:

```
return App\Car::with(['user'])
            ->when($_GET['area']>'', function ($query)  
                { $query-> whereHas('user', function($query) { $query->where('area_id', $_GET['area']); }  ); })->get();
```